# How to plot histograms with decreasing frequency

Tags: r

This code plots a histogram with the high frequency bars to the right in the plot. I need these bars to be to the left, but the following code doesn't do the trick:

```
barplot( sort( table( sysrev$LEAD ) ), axes = T, ylim = c( 0 , 300 ),  cex.names = 0.8, las = 2, decreasing = T)
```

Also, I get a warning that "decreasing" is not a graphical parameter even though it is listed as one in ?barplot.

Comment: Could you paste the outcome of `dput()` on your data?

Comment: Use `decreasing` in the `sort` function: `barplot(sort(table(sysrev$LEAD), decreasing=TRUE), axes = T, ylim = c( 0 , 300),  cex.names = 0.8, las = 2)`

Comment: Of course... Thank you!